# Downloading and saving sharepoint 2013 file into browser client

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I'm trying to get and save files from SharePoint app using REST, the files are located inside the host SP.

Once got the file, I'm saving/downloading it into the browser with a save function.

When I download a .txt, I get file and contents downloaded and saved. 
When I download a .pdf or .doc I get a file but once saved
the content is empty.
The new created file as the correct extension a size but it's like I'm not getting the correct binary for .pdf and .doc files, any suggestion?

Here is my code:

```
var prepareUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + filePath + "')/$value?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

// executes cross domain request
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync(
{
url: prepareUrl,
type: "GET",
binaryStringResponseBody: true,
success: function (data) { readContentsAndSendToIAG(data, fileName) },
error: function (xhr) {
alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText)
}
});
}

function readContentsAndSendToIAG(data, fileName) {
var blob = new Blob([data.body], { type: "application/pdf" });
saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found here, paslatek's comment: 
http://techmikael.blogspot.de/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html?showComment=1407787676122

The problem is that the Microsoft `SP.RequestExecutor.js` is doing this conversion:

```
if (requestInfo.binaryStringResponseBody) {
     responseInfo.body = SP.RequestExecutorInternalSharedUtility.BinaryDecode(xhr.response);
  }
```

but decoding the xhr.response, responseInfo.body is not more binary...

Solution is to patch JavaScript SP.RequestExecutor.js changing the if condition this way:

```
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function(){
   //insert all the content of the original SP.RequestExecutor.js
   //until here
    if (requestInfo.binaryStringResponseBody) {
        responseInfo.body = xhr.response; 
     }

   //add the remaining original code
});
```

As you can see now the if condition becomes:

```
responseInfo.body = xhr.response;
```

Now `data.body` contains binary data and can be used as I needed to create a Blob

```
var blob = new Blob([data.body], { type: "application/pdf" });
saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Comment: You should really add the important part about the answer to your post here. I mean, if the link breaks it will be of no help to future readers

Comment: Done, hope it helps