# Download file using REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

I want to download a file using REST API.

I have a file in a document library /folder. I want download that file, but with a different name.

Edit 1 : Below is my code. i am able to download file on Chrome browser  but data gets corrupted and also not working on IE 10+.

```
function SaveToDisk_blob(blobURL, fileName)
{
var reader = new FileReader();
console.log(blobURL.body)
console.log(fileName.split(".")[1])
var blob = new Blob([blobURL.body], { type: "application/"+fileName.split(".")[1]+"" });
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onload = function (event) {
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = event.target.result;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = fileName || 'unknown file';

    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
};
reader.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
}

function downloadFile(url, fileName)
{

// executes cross domain request
var appweburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
$.getScript(appweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        binaryStringResponseBody: true,
        success: function (blobURL)
        {
            SaveToDisk_blob(blobURL, fileName)
        },
        error: function (xhr)
        {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("downloadFile" + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);

        }
    });
});
}
```

Edit 2: i have made some more change in code.

```
function call_to_rest_binarystring(rest_url)
{
    return $.ajax({
    url: rest_url,
    method: "GET",
});
}

function downloadFile(rest_url, filepath, fileName)
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
if (!window.ActiveXObject) 
{
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = filepath;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    dfd.resolve(true);
}
else if (!!window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)
{
    var rest_return_call = call_to_rest_binarystring(rest_url)
    rest_return_call.done(function (response, status, xhr)
    {


        var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/" + fileName.split(".")[1] + "" });
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);

    });

}
return dfd.promise()
}

var rest_url = "<site name>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/ShareDocument/111.pdf')/openbinarystream"

downloadFile(rest_url, filepath, fileName)
```

still while we download file it is coming blank. i think i am missing something. can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the file, or how to save it? You might get better results on SO for saving the file on disk.  As for retrieving a file, google should reveal results like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx) with instructions on retrieving files.

Comment: @Vadim i am able to solve this issue with help of this article [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111517/downloading-and-saving-sharepoint-2013-file-into-browser-client).   i am not able to create blob data.

Comment: i am following same link but i am not able to solve this issue. when REST call return data, data does not contains body. i think i am missing something.

Comment: Can you edit your question with this info? Put the link, the code you have tried, and any error you may have.

Comment: @wjervis any update on this. data still get corrupted

Comment: [This](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111517/downloading-and-saving-sharepoint-2013-file-into-browser-client?lq=1) link should explain why.  Have you tried not using the `RequestExecutor` library, and instead using `$.ajax()`?  You can still make cross-domain calls with `$.ajax()`, you just use the same url you would for `RequestExecutor`.

Comment: @wjervis i am not able to understated what he want to say. can you please explain me what i have to do. i am using     $.ajax() but still same problem is there. data gets corrupted should i have to add same any headers to     $.ajax() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below are my final working code for downloading file from REST.

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", filepath);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
//setting response-type header to be blob so that we get the file as blob
xhr.onload = function ()
{
//async call
var blobobj = xhr.response;
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobobj, fileName);
//save using msSaveBlob.
dfd.resolve(true);
}
xhr.send();
return dfd.promise()
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use AttachmentFiles endpoint to do this, it is provided when you create or select Item with API.

```
<link  rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AttachmentFiles" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AttachmentFiles" href="Web/Lists(guid'12f9fd2c-0eea-4440-b9d3-a6e445839ba3')/Items(66)/AttachmentFiles" />
```

Main part is

```
href="Web/Lists(guid'12f9fd2c-0eea-4440-b9d3-a6e445839ba3')/Items(66)/AttachmentFiles"
```

You can use both

```
To download      /Items(66)/AttachmentFiles('file.docx')
To upload        /Items(66)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='file.docx')
```

Then u can use a GET method to download file content :

```
executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url: UsePreviousEndPoint,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/atom+xml;type=entry",
        headers: {
                "Accept": "application/atom+xml",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + UserOrAppToken
            },      
        success: function (blobURL)
        {
            SaveToDisk_blob(blobURL, fileName)
        },
        error: function (xhr)
        {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("downloadFile" + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);

        }
    });
```

I guess Digest is only mandatory for POST request.

Comment: this is not helpfull to me as this code getting data from list attachment, i want to fetch data from document library file.

Comment: @RahulDayal use the url to get the file from the document library then.  Other than the url, Albo's code should work.

Comment: @wjervis it is not working, when we download file it does not contains any data. blank file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have direct link to the file, then you can use below approach. But the filename will be the same

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function download(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');        
    a.setAttribute('href', url);        
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but while downloading file i want to change name of the file and code should work on IE and safari browser. above code does not work on IE browser.

Comment: any update on this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your method. I am using REST and needed to add `$value` to the URL get the file content, instead of the file metadata.

```
rc.spActionURL = "https://{mysite}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mysites}/#this.sp365.orisApp#/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/{mysites}/#this.sp365.orisApp#/#arguments.libraryPath#/#arguments.folderName#/#arguments.fileName#')/$value";
```