# Sharepoint REST API Download File Using NodeJs

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, file, nodejs

i'm trying to save file to my drive using NodeJS as backend. So far, i managed to access

```
https://${sites}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents')/Files('test.xlsx')/$value
```

and get the return like;

[image]

so far, no error message appears and i assume the request to the above url is succeed. what can i do with this data? i tried to use `fs.write()` but then when i open the file, it corrupts. any response from you guys is highly appreciated.

thanks.

Note: 
i tried using this method 
[Download sharepoint document with REST as binary file not working for me](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214212/download-sharepoint-document-with-rest-as-binary-file-not-working-for-me?rq=1) but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found out the solution for my case based on this thread :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294470/writing-image-to-local-server

everything works just fine.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are some libraries available for such a task. For example consider [sppull](https://github.com/koltyakov/sppull).
With `sppull` you can easily download file with just a few lines of code:

```
var sppull = require("sppull").sppull;

var context = {
  siteUrl: "http://contoso.sharepoint.com/subsite",
  creds: {
    username: "user@contoso.com",
    password: "_Password_"
  }
};

var options = {
  spRootFolder: "Shared%20Documents/Contracts",
  dlRootFolder: "./Downloads/Contracts"
};
sppull(context, options)....
```

Also check out [sp-download](https://github.com/koltyakov/sp-download)

Comment: When using `sppull`, please do consider the `%20` in the url. I spend a day (!) on this problem when it got to me, that I should just have used a simple space bar `" "` instead. So in my case, it would be `"Shared Documents/Contracts"`. Even if I copy the url from SharePoint and get the `%20` inside the url, I need to replace them with a spacebar.